# How to convert from structure to character or cell array in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, structure, cell

I have a structure and I need one of the fields in this structure (*EEG.event.type*) to be of type character array or cell array in all the cells.
But all the cells in this field are not strings. How to convert their class?

If I check their class `class(EEG.event(1,4))` I obtain `struct`.

First, I thought to check which cells are not strings:

```
nonstr = find(~cellfun(@ischar, {EEG.event.type}));
```

But then I don't know how to convert those cells into strings of characters.
I tried with

```
[EEG.event(nonstr).type]=struct2cell([EEG.event(nonstr).type]);
```

But it gives me this error: `Undefined function 'struct2cell' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`

I also tried

```
[EEG.event(:).type]={EEG.event(:).type};
```

But it says: `Too many output arguments.`

```
type

 '1'
 '601'
 'A_keep'
 'M'
 'A_keep'
 'B_change'
 'M'
 'A_keep'
 'M'
 'A_keep'
 'A_change'
 'M'
 'A_change'
```

Comment: A simple for loop always works (and is often efficient enough)

Comment: I suppose you are using the EEGLAB toolbox. AFAIK, the `type` field is always a string. So type `'1'` should also be string. Have you checked if `nonstr` is an empty matrix?